# Gitlab LFS: Access forbidden. Check your access level

Tags: git, gitlab, git-lfs

A new project was created on the production environment. I forgot to enable LFS and when pushing to it, it didn’t work.

But now, when I do `git lfs push` for any project when adding some LFS file (it can be small so it isn’t some timeout issue) it keeps pushing, and every time it says: `LFS: Access forbidden. Check your access level.`

I try again and every time it tries, it makes a new folder in cache folder of lfs-objects.

I know that project has LFS enabled, because if I disable it it fails at:

- `trace git-lfs: HTTP: POST …/info/lfs/locks/verify`
- `trace git-lfs: HTTP: POST …/info/lfs/objects/batch`

And when LFS is enabled it goes pass this but fails here:

> 22:48:00.649880 trace git-lfs: HTTP:
>   {“objects”:[{“oid”:“7571a85db75aa74d7902aec1fd52d57d2f61bd48d477d319f05e7cbba46155ce”,“size”:2088566784,“actions”:{“upload”:{“href”:"…/gitlab-lfs/objects/7571a85db75aa74d7902aec1fd52d57d2f61bd48d477d319f05e7cbba46155ce/2088566784",“header”:{“Authorization”:“Basic
>   ZGVuaXNvOiE0S3JhdG5vU3Jhbmpldkl0YWxpamkh”}}}}]} 22:48:00.649880 trace
>   git-lfs: tq: starting transfer adapter “basic” Git LFS: (0 of 1 files)
>   0 B / 1.95 GB 22:48:00.650380 trace git-lfs: HTTP: PUT
>   …/gitlab-lfs/objects/7571a85db75aa74d7902aec1fd52d57d2f61bd48d477d319f05e7cbba46155ce/2088566784
>   Git LFS: (0 of 1 files) 1.95 GB / 1.95 GB 22:50:48.049854 trace
>   git-lfs: HTTP: 403 22:50:48.049854 trace git-lfs: HTTP:
>   {“message”:“Access forbidden. Check your access
>   level.”,“documentation_url”:“https://git.comtrade.com/help”}
>   22:50:48.050354 trace git-lfs: tq: retrying object
>   7571a85db75aa74d7902aec1fd52d57d2f61bd48d477d319f05e7cbba46155ce: LFS:
>   Access forbidden. Check your access level. 22:50:48.050354 trace
>   git-lfs: tq: enqueue retry #1 for
>   “7571a85db75aa74d7902aec1fd52d57d2f61bd48d477d319f05e7cbba46155ce”
>   (size: 2088566784)

Any idea what could be the problem?

This still works on test environment. I’m looking for differences but can’t find them.